# Does Google Analytics measure the traffic of Foxtel ads?

Tags: google-analytics, ads

If Foxtel is watched on PC or a Mac in a browser, it does shows ads. Will Google Analytics track traffic from these ads to our website when we advertise on foxtel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes, if you tag your links correctly using UTM variables. See here for more https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

UTM variables are query string parameters added to URL and delivered as part of the page url to Google Analytics (GA) allowing it to attribute the traffic correctly.

Three required parameters are;

- utm_source - traffic source
- utm_medium - campaign medium
- utm_campaign - campaign medium

So in your example, the ad destination could be;
www.example.com/landing_page.html?utm_source=**foxtel**&utm_medium=**cpm**&utm_campaign=**my_first_campaign**

This way, such traffic will be attributed to **foxtel/cpm** traffic/source and to **my_first_campaign** campaign

Comment: Welcome to stack.   Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.